# Use Python Requests to access MediaWiki text

Tags: python, python-requests

Is there a way I can use the python requests to access the body of a MediaWiki article. As you may recall, you use the requests module by sending a dictionary consisting of a key for accessing each HTML element you wish to see.

The bodies of many articles, for example, are written in a format such as:

```
</div><textarea tabindex="1" accesskey="," id="wpTextbox1" cols="80" rows="25" style="" lang="en" dir="ltr" name="wpTextbox1">
(body of the article)
</textarea><div class='editOptions'>
```

How could I access the text contained between these two HTML headers? I tried 'wpTextbox1' : '....', but this did not work. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, requests doesn't parse HTML for you, it just return the HTTP response as pure text.

You can try [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which parses html and can return the text of a particular HTML element.

Comment: I've considered that for get requests. What about for post requests, though, where I edit the text?

Comment: With POST, you need to check if the server expects a form, or maybe JSON data in request body, and call requests.post accordingly. But if the page has CSRF protection, such requests will fail if you don't provide CSRF token. I suggest you inspect the post request from browser DevTools first and decide what to do.

Comment: I've already figured out how to deal with edit tokens. I posted this question on the requests github page, to see if they have a way to deal with this. Thanks for your help though.